# MVC IIS Memory Leak

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Trying to figure out why this is happening. I am not sure why. I have an MVC view that calls a partial view on a timed interval to update the data being shown. When it refreshes, the W3WP memory usage climbs a bit each time, eventually, hitting the MB limit for the app pool causing it to recycle.

It looks like what is happening in the memory profiler is the action gets called to get new data from SQL and send it back to the partial view in my model. The memory climbs when the SQL actions take place.

So it is like that model data is being stored in memory each time and not let go or cleaned up. What is extra weird is if I close the browser down, the memory isn't freed up either it will just stay where ever it was peaked.

I can slow the progress by doing a GC.Collect after the SQL grab but that is not a solution. It eventually still climbs but much slower. What am I missing here? this is the first instance I've ever seen of this in all the years doing this. All my other MVC apps don't act like this although none of them refresh data on a timed interval.

Data is refreshed using jquery load.

Controller Action:

```
 [OutputCache(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult getRollCall(int id)
        {

            Models.RollCall rc = new Models.RollCall(id);


            return PartialView("_RollCall", rc);
        }
```

Client:

```
function updateGridData() {

            $("#divRollCall").empty();
            //Get the partial view.
            var URL = "@Url.Action("getRollCall","SignIn")" + "?id=" + $("#INSTANCEID").val();

            $("#divRollCall").load(URL);
        }
```

SQL is just filling to Lists with about 30 rows of data each with 4 columns and a second list with 2 columns, X number of items but probably in reality no more than 20. It is just some squares on the screen with names in them. Nothing spectacular. Connection is disposed.

Comment: Please provide SQL and MVC code samples.

Comment: try to set the dispose after getting the data. could you share the RollCall method?